# How to calculate weighted indegree in GraphX

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am new to GraphX and exploring example flight data analysis found on online.http://www.sparktutorials.net/analyzing-flight-data:-a-gentle-introduction-to-graphx-in-spark

I tried calculating inDegrees (understand how many incoming flights to an airport) but I see value which corresponds to unique routes incoming to the airport. This means that if there exist more than one flight between a particular source and destination, lets' say 5, I am seeing only 1 for this route. What I want is something similar in the line of weighted degrees where in while calculating indegrees, the weight associated with the edge should be considered. This weight value is in edge._attr parameter which is not being considered for the computing degrees.
Here is the my code block

```
 val df_1 = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                            .option("header", "true")
                            .load("file:///home/user/testData.csv")

 val flightsFromTo = df_1.select($"Source",$"Target")

  // calculate the number of airport codes present in the data
 val airportCodes = df_1.select($"Source", $"Target")
                          .flatMap(x => Iterable(x(0).toString, x(1).toString))

 val airportVertices: RDD[(VertexId, String)] = airportCodes.distinct()
                  .map(x =>  (MurmurHash.stringHash(x), x))

 val uniqueJourneyLegs = flightsFromTo.map(x => ((MurmurHash.stringHash(x(0).toString),MurmurHash.stringHash(x(1).toString)), 1))
                                  .reduceByKey(_+_).map(x => Edge(x._1._1, x._1._2,x._2))

val graph = Graph(airportVertices, uniqueJourneyLegs, defaultAirport)
val inDegrees = graph.inDegrees.join(airportVertices).sortBy(_._2._1, ascending=false).take(10)
val outDegrees = graph.outDegrees.join(airportVertices).sortBy(_._2._1, ascending=false).take(10)

  // Top 10 Indegrees
println("Top 10 indegrees - > " )
inDegrees.foreach{println}

 // Top 10 out degrees
println("Top 10 outDegrees -> " ) 
outDegrees.foreach{println}        
// Top 10 out degrees
println("Top 10 outDegrees -> " ) 
outDegrees.foreach{println}
```

Can someone point to me right link or provide me an hint to solve this?. Each Edge has an attribute parameter called _attr that has number of flights between a particular source and destination. For instance, there are 5 flights between bangalore and chennai in a day. But, the graph.inDegrees, consider this as 1 indegree, that is, unique route. HEnce, I get only unique flight routes that are flying in to a source.

Comment: Can you please reformulate what "functional question" you are trying to solve ?

Comment: try to see [this asnwer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648558/how-to-sum-edge-weights-with-graphx)